# Design for passive power backup for ESP32 for a few milliseconds

Tags: esp32, supercapacitor, backup

I am designing a logger system with an ESP32 in which the logs are uploaded to the IoT cloud and parallelly logged to a local SD card. On Power loss detection, I want the ESP32 dump all the data that is in its buffer memory into the SD Card. I have measured the time taken for dumping the values on the SD card and the current required by the system.

Time taken to dump logs into the memory card - 110 ms.
current required for the during operation 80mA @ 5V

I planned to use a capacitor to provide power, but it requires a 225 mF capacitor, which is too huge.
I tried of using a CR2032 coin cell as a power backup, but it cannot provide the required current.

What other solution can I implement to make the short power backup?

Comment: Welcome! How did you come up with your capacity? There are huge supercapacitors like this one: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Lelon/SCMDVLT3R6105ZVH190004E?qs=lc2O%252BfHJPVY5Ohj4wQJ2Uw%3D%3D

Comment: Power storage in capacitors is \$0.5*C*V^2\$, so if you can put your storage at a higher voltage, then it could provide power longer, depending on your power supplies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Time taken to dump logs into the memory card - 110 ms. current required for the during operation 80mA @ 5V

Assuming you are not using AMS1117 "L"DO for 3V3 but something more tasteful like LDL1117, or any regulator which actually delivers low dropout and good transient response...

If the supply cap C is charged at 4.5V when power is lost... assuming 0.3V dropout in the LDO, and the ESP32 and SD require 3.3V this means after drawing i=80mA for dt=0.11s voltage on the input cap must not have dropped  more than dv=4.2-3.3=1.2V.

i = C dv/dt thus C = i dt/dv = 7333µF

Therefore a 10.000µF 6.3V cap should be adequate. I have no idea where the  huge µF value in the question comes from.

However you must ensure that the data given to the SD card was actually written, not just transferred to it and sitting in its RAM buffers waiting to be written. Otherwise it will be lost. If you are using a filesystem then beware, flush times may not always be the same.

Other options include:

If this is mains powered, and you have control over the power supply, then the AC-DC switching power supply is definitely going to store enough energy in the primary high voltage capacitor to last long enough to flush your data to SD. However you need to detect loss of mains, which may be more complicated than adding a large capacitor.

If 5V is derived from a higher supply voltage via a regulator (linear or switching) then... first, you probably don't need 5V because ESP32 and SD both use 3V3. Second, the capacitor would be better placed on this higher supply voltage, because that would allow more dV before it runs out, hence it'll work with a smaller cap.

Another solution is to write temporary data to internal flash, not using SPIFFS but rather bare metal. When erasing SPI flash you have to erase a full page, which will set all the bytes in it to 0xFF... but when writing you can just write one byte at a time. If what you are writing is not
xFF, then it's possible to find the last data that was written before power loss.

ESP32 also has several kB of RTC SRAM whose contents are preserved during deep sleep and power down. You can't power the whole micro with a coin cell, but I think you can power the RTC and its associated memory block with a coin cell or memory backup supercap. Unlike the SPI flash this doesn't wear out, but it needs a backup supply.